# How to extract MetaData from Bim 360 Plans?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I can see a table of results under Bim 360 Plans which includes a fields like Name, Title, Set, Version, LastUpdated, UpdatedBy. See screenshot below:

[BIM 360 Plans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XJtX.png)

However I cannot get all the fields from the API. Title, Set and Version are missing.

"attributes": {
"displayName": "A101 - Site Plan",
"createTime": "2021-10-15T14:38:17.0000000Z",
"createUserId": "P49WLFCASZNJ",
"createUserName": "Walker Lockard",
"lastModifiedTime": "2021-10-15T14:38:17.0000000Z",
"lastModifiedUserId": "P49WLFCASZNJ",
"lastModifiedUserName": "Walker Lockard",
"hidden": false,
"reserved": false,

Question: Which API do I use to extract the Bim 360 Plans Data and do you have an example CURL for that to extract Title, Set and Version?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the information you provided is limited. From my test, you will need to find the `versionNumber` from its version tip, which type is `versions`. like the below. The snippet your share is an item that type is `items`.

```json
{
    "type": "versions",
    "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.34Xvlw1jTcSQ_XkIVh07cg?version=2",
    "attributes": {
        "name": "3 Appr. Date I ita Extraction And Multileaders Samole ■",
        "displayName": "3 Appr. Date I ita Extraction And Multileaders Samole ■",
        "createTime": "2018-12-11T08:04:08.0000000Z",
        "createUserId": "",
        "createUserName": "",
        "lastModifiedTime": "2020-12-23T07:38:03.0000000Z",
        "lastModifiedUserName": "Eason Kang",
        "versionNumber": 2,
// ...
```

Unfortunately, there is no API that supports getting `Sets` and `title` at this moment. We apologize for the inconveniences.